# React hook infinity loop vs context

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-context

I have created a react hook useAuth like this:

```
    const useApiCall = () => {
      return useQuery({
        queryKey: ["/load"],
        queryFn: async () => {
          const resp = await fetch(
            "https://api.publicapis.org/entries"
          ).then((response) => response.json());

          return resp.entries;
        }
      });
    };

    function useAuth() {
      const {
        data: user = null,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        error,
        refetch
      } = useApiCall();

      return useMemo(
        () => ({
          user,
          isLoading: isLoading || isFetching,
          authenticated: !user && !isFetching && !isLoading,
          error,
          refetch
        }),
        [user, isLoading, isFetching, error, refetch]
      );
    }
```

And I use this hook every where I need the auth info like user or check if the user is authenticated.

The problem with this hook is an infinity loops like this code examlpe:

https://codesandbox.io/s/proud-frog-9kh6oh?file=/src/useAuth.js:85-712

If I transfrom my hook to context I can use the hook every where without looping:

```
    const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
      const {
        data: user = null,
        isLoading,
        isFetching,
        error,
        refetch
      } = useMe();

      const values = useMemo(
        () => ({
          user,
          isLoading: isLoading || isFetching,
          authenticated: user && !isFetching && !isLoading,
          error,
          refetch
        }),
        [
          user,
          isLoading,
          isFetching,
          error,
          refetch
        ]
      );
      return <AuthContext.Provider value={values}>{children}</AuthContext.Provider>;
    };

    const useAuth = () => {
      const context = useContext(AuthContext);
      if (!context) {
        throw new Error('useAuth must be used within the AuthProvider');
      }
      return context;
    };
```

Can some one please explain this behavior ?

Comment: Hello can you show useAuth hook please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set usequery `enabled` option to false to make query once.  You should also use `onSuccess` method to make redux `dispatch`.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating the infinite loop yourself because you're using:

```
isLoading: isLoading || isFetching,
```

Here's what happens:

- your `App.js` calls `useAuth`, and then you only render the loading text
- loading succeeds, and you render `<AppLayout />`
- this in turn calls `useAuth` again
- because data is stale per default and a new component (observer) mounts, we'll get a background refetch
- this will set the query into `isFetching` state (but not `isLoading`)
- because you've re-wired `isLoading` to also include `|| isFetching`, your `isLoading` is now `true` again.
- this will unmount your `AppLayout` again and just render the loading text again
- when this fetch succeeds, we go again to mounting the `AppLayout`, and the process repeats

Bottom line: don't unmount your App when `isFetching` is true. Additionally, maybe set a `staleTime` if you don't want instant background refetches.